# Effectively sending/streaming real-time video

Tags: c#, video-streaming, real-time

I am developing a game where I want to stream the camera’s output from a server (which renders everything) to several clients. For simplicity, I am ignoring all audio data.

Currently, I record the camera’s render as a bitmap with a 400x300 resolution, and then I convert it to JPEG, add a time stamp and send it to the client over UDP.

With given resolution, my payload size varies from 13KB to 20KB. How can I make it more effective?

Comment: Questions on the theme of "what is the best..." typically don't make for a good fit for stackoverflow. Can you refine your question to ask about a specific improvement, rather than leaving us to guess what "more effective" means to you?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for point that out.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose jpg? Have you considered RTSP/RTP with some more efficient video codec? Have you considered rendering at the clients?

Comment: I have considered RTP but so far I have failed in implement it (or finding a library I can use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a video codec, not an image codec.

JPEG is appropriate for single images.  (There is MJPEG, which is effectively a hack on this... but it's not all that great of quality.)

Most devices have a hardware codec for something like H.264 that you can use.  If not, you can use H.264 in software, or use a free and open codec like VP8 or VP9... just be aware that those take more CPU for encoding.  (Not that it will matter much at such a low resolution.)

Comment: The advantage of video formats is that they use inter frame compression, right? But if I am sending single frames as early as I render them, why is much better to use video codecs?

Comment: @EricMarchettiSantos You'll send each frame into the codec.  If you want low latency video, there are configurations for H.264, VP8, and VP9 that can work in this mode.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to delay the first frame to wait for the next ones? Could you recommend me further reading into that?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to keep the image dimensions, there are 2 things I can think of which can reduce the payload:

- [JPEG image quality](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47055/how-can-we-talk-about-the-resolution-of-a-jpeg-file) - Reducing the JPEG image quality can drastically reduce its size.

Here's a calculation I just made:

400 x 300 JPEG with 10/10 quality = 29.6KB.

400 x 300 JPEG with 8/10 quality = 19.6KB.

400 x 300 JPEG with 5/10 quality = 8.7KB.

400 x 300 JPEG with 2/10 quality = 5.6KB.

So, as you can see, losing 0.2 quality results in losing 1/3 of the image weight, which is significant.

- Framerate - Most cameras today can support up to 200 FPS, which is totally unnecessary for smooth videos. You can use 20 FPS and still get a good quality video. Reducing the FPS will linearly reduce the payload.